# Access POJO properties using ModelDriven in Struts 2?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am using `ModelDriven` in Struts 2 such that my model object has inside itself another object with properties. I am doing an AJAX call and want my model object to be filled by the `User`.

**JSP:**

```
<s:select list="#session.circleIdNameMap"
  headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Circle"
  name="id.circleId" id="selectCircleDropDown"
  onchange="findTspNameIdMap(this.value)">
</s:select>
```

**JS:**

```
 $.ajax({   
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/gma/findTspNameIdMap.action',
    data: 
    { 
        id.circleId: circleId,
        minNumberOc: $("[name='minNumberOc']").val(),
        minDurationOc: $("[name='minDurationOc']").val(),
    },
```

However, here in firebug I get an error

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
id.circleId: circleId,
```

but other direct propeties like `minNumberOc` work ok but not `id.anything`. I am posting my model object and the Action class.

**GmaThresholdParameter:**

```
public class GmaThresholdParameter implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private GmaThresholdParameterPK id;
   //getter/setters of id
```

**GmaThresholdParameterPK:**

```
public class GmaThresholdParameterPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="CIRCLE_ID")
    private int circleId;

    @Column(name="TSP_ID")
    private int tspId;

    private String flag;
   //getter/setters
```

**Action class:**

```
public class ConfigureTspThresholdAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ModelDriven<GmaThresholdParameter>{

    private Map<String,String> circleIdNameMap;
// MODEL object
    GmaThresholdParameter gmaThresholdParameters = new GmaThresholdParameter();
   .....
   ...
   public GmaThresholdParameter getGmaThresholdParameters() {
    return gmaThresholdParameters;
}


public void setGmaThresholdParameters(
        GmaThresholdParameter gmaThresholdParameters) {
    this.gmaThresholdParameters = gmaThresholdParameters;
}

@Override
public GmaThresholdParameter getModel() {
    return gmaThresholdParameters;
}
```

How to set properties corresponding to `id`? Why is it giving an error in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it giving an error in Firebug?

Because you have a trailing comma at the statement below

```
minDurationOc: $("[name='minDurationOc']").val(),
```

Comment: I checked my code in that I don't put the ','  at the end, still it gives the error. Is it sure that id.circleId: circleId works? Is struts able to pick getters even in AJAX?

Comment: And as the error says 'missing :(colon) at id.cricleId: circleId' after id. So it expects a colon after id. So does id.anthying: xyz actually work?

Comment: `id.circleId` should be in quotes, without it such name is invalid.